# Distance between Iris and Camera lens

Tags: java, android, opencv, distance

I'm using Eclipse to build simple app for Android.
My purpose is calculating distance between 2 iris and camera lens.

I have detected two iris using OpenCV.

What is the next step? Please show me the relative formula to calculate.

Any idea will be appreciate.

Comment: next you'll need a estimate the size of the person's head (based on age maybe?) and the aperture of the lens (the more the lens is a fisheye the closer the irises will be). dont think it can be practically done.

Comment: if distance_between_iris=image.width then distance_to_lens=0. Now if d_b_i~0 then d_t_l~max_dist. You have two known points, do linear interpolation for the rest.